# New Update of Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Today, I opened an old project that I had to do some updates and noticed that I had an update in XAmarin.Forms. I updated, but when I updated my project started to give errors in InitializeComponent.The previous version and it worked. Has anyone had the same problem as me and has been able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to remove all "bin" and "obj" directories and do a clean of your Solution. Rebuild first the XF project then the Android / iOS project.

Comment: Ok. I will try your soluction. it's strange, I create a new project and even then it comes with the same error but if I put the previous version works